# Is there a mechanism to filter my search results on Stack Overflow by dates?

Tags: support, search

For example, I want to search for the questions with the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [core-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-location) tags. And I went to order it by the most voted, but only for a question written in the past two years.

This is more of a design bug. Because as a user I expect that when I click on 'Advanced search tips' I will get a list of all things I can do. But then there is something more advanced that you can do, but you have to click on *another* link!

Something from the flow/user experience/wording needs to change.

Comment: You can already do that with the [`date`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) search option.

Comment: I have a userscript: [Advanced Search Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) that might interest you...

Comment: Last time I used date filtering to get the excavator badge on a site (it requires to edit a post inactive since at least a half year). I searched with `created: ..180d`, sort by votes, I went to the last page, I found a fixable post, and fixed it. And I got my badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to click on “[visit our help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)” here:

[image]

Though it doesn’t make any sense to name something “Advanced search” and then have another advanced search at the bottom.

Thanks to Sebastian Simon for pointing this out.

Comment: Haven't you heard about [recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/642302)?

Comment: [You silver tongued devil, you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXpR2tMgvtE)